# how to make div responsive inside viewport?

Tags: html, css

I have many `div` in a `div` tag like this:

```css
#mycontent > div {
  width: 14.28%;
}
```

```html
<div id="myheader">some header content</div>

<div class="container" id="mycontent">
  <div class="outerdiv" id="row1">
    <div class="cells">Sun</div>
    <div class="cells">Mon</div>
    <div class="cells">Tue</div>
    <div class="cells">Wed</div>
    <div class="cells">Thu</div>
    <div class="cells">Fri</div>
    <div class="cells">Sat</div>
  </div>

  <div class="outerdiv" id="row6">
    <div class="cells"></div>
    <div class="cells"></div>
    <div class="cells"></div>
    <div class="cells"></div>
    <div class="cells"></div>
    <div class="cells"></div>
    <div class="cells"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="mydetails">extra contents here</div>
```

how do I style this kind of structure to make the `#myheader` and `#mycontent` to fill 100% of the original viewport, while the `#mydetails` is below them? is it even possible?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you not to use `width: 14.28%`. Remove it. If you do, your `.outerdiv` items will automatically fit inside the div, no matter how many of them are.

```
#myheader, 
#mycontent,
.outerdiv {
    width: 100%;
}

.outerdiv {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.outerdiv > div {
    display: block;
    flex-basis: 0;
    flex-grow: 1;
    flex-shrink: 1;
    padding: .75rem;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.outerdiv {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}
```

this should do the trick.